# Move-SPSite on Top Level

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Can I move the Top Level site to a new content database. When researching, only site collections (.../sites/...) are mentioned.
I would like to confirm if the parent site can be moved the same way before breaking something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tested it quickly and it worked without any issue. Only a IISReset is needed after moving.

```
Move-SPSite -Identity "http://my.fancy.domain/" -DestinationDatabase "MyNewContentDatabase"
```

Comment: Finally had time to take care of this. Worked like a charm!